# Hide JQ Error Messages from Curl command

Tags: bash, curl, jq

I'm running the following curl command:

```
installer_to_delete=$(curl -s -u username:password "URL/api/search/dates?dateFields=created&from=${Two_Years_Ago}&today&repos=npm-local-lrn" | jq -r '.results[].uri'|sed 's=/api/storage==')

if [[ $installer_to_delete == "" ]]
then
    echo "No installers found"
else
    for installer in $installer_to_delete
    do
    echo $installer
    done
fi
```

The error/output for this is:

```
assertion "cb == jq_util_input_next_input_cb" failed: file "/usr/src/ports/jq/jq-1.5-3.x86_64/src/jq-1.5/util.c", line 371, function: jq_util_input_get_position
```

It shows this output whenever the Curl command can't find a file. How can I silence the JQ error from popping up whenever it can't find a file?

Comment: There's no need for `sed` here -- `jq` can do string replacements internally.

Answer (score 4):

One (not so hot) option would be to redirect STDERR to /dev/null:

```
jq  -r '.results[].uri' 2> /dev/null
```

Since there is clearly a possibility of error, a better option might be to break up the pipeline into steps so you can handle different errors as appropriate along the way.

By the way, that assertion indicates there's some kind of bug in jq itself. Would you be able to show us the corresponding output of `curl`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `curl --fail` to only continue on to run the `jq` command if the `curl` succeeds:

```
url="URL/api/search/dates?dateFields=created&from=${Two_Years_Ago}&today&repos=npm-local-lrn"

if result=$(curl -s --fail  -u username:password "$url"); then
  readarray -t installers < <(jq -r '.results[].uri' <<<"$result" | sed 's=/api/storage==')
  if (( ${#installers[@]} )); then
    for installer in "${installers_to_delete[@]}"; do
      echo "$installer"
    done
  else
    echo "Empty list of installers retrieved" >&2
  fi
else
  echo "HTTP error retrieving installers" >&2
fi
```